# Invalid Query Locator error on simple query

Tags: soql, rest-api

I am trying to execute a very simple query on a standard Case object via the REST API but am receiving an **INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR** error.

My query is:

`SELECT Status FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber='00001039' LIMIT 1`

which works in the developer console, but not via the REST API:

```
https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/q=SELECT+Status+FROM+Case+WHERE+CaseNumber='00001039'+LIMIT+1
```

Error response: 400 - BadRequest

```
[{"message":"invalid query locator","errorCode":"INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR"}]
```

I've also tried escaping the quote char in the URL with %27, without any luck:

```
https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/q=SELECT+Status+FROM+Case+WHERE+CaseNumber=%2700001039%27+LIMIT+1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

400 means your request is not correct. Check that you are missing `?` mark in your REST query. Try below

```
https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+Status+FROM+Case+WHERE+CaseNumber='00001039'+LIMIT+1
```

Note that [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) is a good tool to test your request